# Pylint: Specifying exception names in the overgeneral-exceptions option without module name is deprecated

Tags: python, pylint

> pylint: Command line or configuration file:1: UserWarning: Specifying
> exception names in the overgeneral-exceptions option without module
> name is deprecated and support for it will be removed in pylint 3.0.
> Use fully qualified name (maybe 'builtins.BaseException' ?) instead.

Getting PyLint error.
I dont have any Except clause in my file and yet I see this error.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is just a warning for future pylint releases, you can ignore it. If you want to address it now you will need to open your `.pylintrc` configuration file (should be located at `~/.pylintrc`) and replace:

```
overgeneral-exceptions=BaseException,
                       Exception
```

with:

```
overgeneral-exceptions=builtins.BaseException,
                       builtins.Exception
```

Answer (score -1):

This could happen when you import custom Python files/packages without initializing them. The recommendation is to create a `__init__.py` to mark a directory as a Python package.

**Problematic code**

```
# your file
your_dir/data_processing/read.py

# import
from data_processing import read # pylint warning
```

**Correct Code**

```
# your file
your_dir/data_processing/read.py
your_dir/data_processing/__init__.py  

# import
from data_processing import read
```